# Connection string with relative path to the database file

Tags: c#, string, connection, sql-server-ce

I load data from sdf database in winforms App. I  use full path to the  database file . Example :

```
conn = new SqlCeConnection

{

ConnectionString ="Data Source=F:\\My Documents\\Project1\\bin\\Debug\\Database.sdf"

};
```

I d like use a relative path to the database file. For example. I have sdf file in folder  F:\My Documents\Project1\bin\Debug\Data\file.sdf  and I want use relative path in connection string. 
Any advice ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have a relative path? what you typed "F:\My Documents\Project1\bin\Debug\Data\file.sdf" is also a full path.  A relative path would be something like "\data\file.sdf" if your app was already running from "F:\My Documents\Project1\bin\"

Answer (score 99):

Relative path:

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf";
```

Modifying DataDirectory as executable's path:

```
string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

Comment: To learn more about the **DataDirectory** term, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx (it's at the end of the document)

Answer (score 8):

Try this code to the working directory if database file exists like below.

D:\HMProject\DataBase\HMProject.sdf

```
string Path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string[] appPath =  Path.Split(new string[] { "bin" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", appPath[0]);
```

**Connection string for .sdf file**

`<add name="LocalDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Client.HMProject.csdl|res://*/Client.HMProject.ssdl|res://*/Client.HMProject.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\HMProjectDB.sdf;Password=HMProject;Persist Security Info=False;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Thanks

ck.Nitin (TinTin)

Answer (score 4):

Relative to what, your application ? If so then you can simply get the applications current Path with :

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

And append it to the connection string

Comment: You can't just "append it to the connection string". You'd have to parse the connection string, extract the data source value, prepend the current directory and then rebuild the connection string. This is non-trivial.

Answer (score 4):

After several strange errors with relative paths in connectionstring I felt the need to post this here.

*When using "|DataDirectory|" or "~" you are not allowed to step up and out using "../" !*

Example is using several projects accessing the same localdb file placed in one of the projects.

*" ~/../other" and " |DataDirectory|/../other" will fail*

Even if it is clearly written [at MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) the errors it gave where a bit unclear so hard to find and could not find it here at SO.

Answer (score 4):

In your config file give the relative path

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf";
```

Change the DataDirectory to your executable path

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

If you are using EntityFramework, then you can set the DataDirectory path in your Context class

Comment: This worked for me. But in the ef core there should be a space after the equal sign and no back slash and space before the data base file name. Otherwise it does not detect the DataDirectory.
Example: `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= |DataDirectory|my_database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"`

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>  
  <appSettings>  
    <!--FailIfMissing=false -->  
    <add key="DbSQLite" value="data source=|DataDirectory|DB.db3;Pooling=true;FailIfMissing=false"/>  
  </appSettings>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: do not store connection strings in <appSettings>. They have their own section.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try with below code block, which is exactly what you're looking for:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection
{
    ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\Database.sdf"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
string Connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\myPath\\myFile.db")
    + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";
```

I'm querying an XLSX file so don't worry about any of the other stuff in the connection string but the Data Source.

So my answer is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\myPath\\myFile.db")
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the web.config file. I added to Sobhan's answer, thanks btw.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="listdb" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db\listdb.sdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Where "db" becomes my database directory instead of "App_Data" directory.

And opened normally with:

var db = Database.Open("listdb");

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to specify the relative file path for a database connected to a Windows Forms application. I was able to resolve the issue by following the directions for adding a data source to Windows Forms from Microsoft (e.g., [for connecting an Access database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms?view=vs-2017)).

By using this method, Visual Studio will set the relative file paths to your database for you instead of trying to set it manually. If your database is external to your application, it will create a copy of the database and add it to your application in the proper location. Although you can manually alter you connection string in App.config and/or Settings.settings or within one of your scripts, I've found this method to be error prone. Instead, I've found it best to follow the Microsoft instructions, in general.