# How do I retain database connectivity, with my project, when the source file path changes?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using a **Microsoft Access Database** in my project; saved to the bin folder. What can I do, to ensure connectivity to that database, when the file path changes?

> Imports System.Data.OleDb
>   Public Class Form3
>
> Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
>
> Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
>
> Dim ds As New DataSet
>
> Dim str1 As String

```
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AARVIII\Documents\DATABASE\MP1.accdb"
```

Comment: I believe you are trying to say that you want your database connection string to be dynamic. So when you move your app folder the project can stil find you database. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried a Data Source of `.\MP1.accdb`?  Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001980/app-config-connection-string-relative-path, relative paths are valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection string locates your database in a fixed position valid only on your PC.
A simple workaround is to use the **|DataDirectory|** substitution string.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                       "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MP1.accdb"
```

in this way, you can control the location of your database through code.
Usually (for a desktop application) the **|DataDirectory|** substitution string points the same folder where you have installed your application, but you need to have permission to write there and any kind of active database requires write permissions on its files. So this is not the best location for database files.

However you could change the location pointed by DataDirectory using code like this. (Of course put it BEFORE any attempt to talk to the database)

```
 ' Prepare a string pointing to a subfolder of the common application data 
 Dim appFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
 Dim dbFolder = Path.Combine(appFolder, "MyAppFolder")

 ' Create the folder if it doesn't exist.
 Directory.CreateDirectory(dbFolder)

 ' Change the substitution string kept by DataDirectory
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", dbFolder)
```

Now the target directory for your database will be C:\programdata\myappfolder where your application has read/write permissions

More info on DataDirectory

[Where is DataDirectory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-)
[DataDirectory where is documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409358/ado-net-datadirectory-where-is-this-documented)

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you should use:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "MP1.accdb"
```

And have the database file in the same folder as you startup .exe...

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple code and I can move the folder any where

```
conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..\myDatabase.mdb"
```

Make sure to save the access file in the bin folder for this connection string to work.