# quartz.config to read from sqlite file in the same directory

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-services, quartz.net

I have set up my `Quartz.Net` Windows service and it works just fine. I also have set up an `AdoJobStore` so that my jobs are stored in an *Sqlite* database file. This is my `quartz.config` part for Sqlite:

```
# SQLite settings
quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz
quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
quartz.jobStore.dataSource = default
quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SQLiteDelegate, Quartz
quartz.dataSource.default.provider = SQLite-10
quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString = Data Source=C:\Server\jobs.sqlite;Version=3
```

As you see in the `connectionString` value I have `C:\Server\jobs.sqlite` as the location of the database. Since my `jobs.sqlite` is always located in the Server folder, I want this setting to always read the file from the current directory i.e. same directory that my `quartz.config` is. How can I tell Quartz.Net to read from the current directory? Otherwise I have to change this value every time I move the folder.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001980/app-config-connection-string-relative-path ?

Comment: @MarkoLahma genius. wanna post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the SQLite connection string to be app relative, see the answer here:

[App.config connection string relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001980/app-config-connection-string-relative-path)