# Raspberry Pi, C#, Monodevelop,Sqlite - no such table, filename unknown

Tags: c#, sqlite, raspberry-pi, monodevelop

I have small test Sqlite database on my Raspberry Pi2.

Connection string is:

```
con = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=test.db,version3");
```

If I want fetch data, I use:

```
cmd = new SqliteCommand("SELECT * FROM users",con);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read()){ 
.... 
}
```

I get this Exception:

```
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite error
no such table: users
at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Prepare (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection cnn,
System.String strSql, Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement previous,
UInt32 timeoutMS, System.String& strRemain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.BuildNextCommand () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'll grateful for whatever advice.

Comment: Are you _really_ sure you have a table called `users`? Maybe it is `user` or case sensitive issue?

Comment: Ensure you have the rig path to the database.

Comment: Table users exists, because If I try this through console:  sqllite3 test.db; SELECT * FROM users; - it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your connection string, it should be like this: `"Data Source={path-to-your-database-file}test.db;Version=3;"`

Comment: Table users certainly exists, because If I try this through console:  `sqllite3 test.db;` and  `SELECT * FROM users;` - it works.

Comment: @skybedy changed my answer

Comment: I tried `con = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=test.db;Version=3;")` , however without success.

Comment: Is the test.db at the location where it is expected by SQLite? I highly suspect it now looks at the wrong location (e.g. location of executing assembly). See this SO answer for some inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5003238/3997704

Comment: Bingo. Thank you very much. I wrote "Data Source=/home/pi/test.db,version3" and seems, that it works fine.

Comment: Great to hear! Accept answer?

Answer (score 0):

A database file with the name `test.db,version3` does not yet exist, so it is created.

Connection string parameters always must use an equals sign: `Version=3`.