# SQLite connection string relative path

Tags: c#, database, path

I'm trying to figure out how to implement relative path instead of the absolute one so I can use the project on other computers. Currently, my connection looks like this

```
string dataSource = "Data Source=C:\\Users\\John\\source\\repos\\BloodBankNET\\Baza\\PravaBaza.sqlite";
```

I'll be sending the folder `BloodBankNET` to the other computer, so ideally it would look something like this

```
..\\BloodBankNET\\Baza\\PravaBaza.sqlite
```

Comment: If you are going to a Network drive you do not want the leading "..\\".  It is not relative you want the root of the Network folder.  You could map a network drive and use the letter.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered here: [App.config connection string relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001980/app-config-connection-string-relative-path).
You can use a dot (.) in your data source. Here is an example: `data source=.\data\myDatabase.sqlite`