# How do I fix a Database Authentication Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I run my aspx file I get this:

```
      No error message available, result code: DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED(0x80040E4D).
```

Why is this happening exactly?

Here is my web.config file:

```
 <add name="2007 Database  05-12-2013(Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24)
  ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
  Source=" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

and here relative path in my `aspx` file:

```
<script runat="server">
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["2007 Database 
    05-12-2013(Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24)ConnectionString"]
   .ConnectionString + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Anderson\2007 
    Database 05-12-2011 (Esfahanian's conflicted copy 2013-06-24).mdb");
</script>
```

Comment: The web.config string looks like it's missing some pieces, but I've not worked with the Jet.OLEDB before, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string is definitely not right. The "Name" property is only used internally by your application, in this case, the .aspx file. You need to have the name of the database file somewhere in the actual connection string.

Here is my favorite source for all things connection string:
http://www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: I don't see anything on make the path relative, all the examples show absolute

Comment: Google is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833640/connection-string-with-relative-path-to-the-database-file