# ASP.Net database connection string without drive/user/documents

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

so I have a question on asp.net sql stringconnection. So basically what I have now, is

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\mateusz\Desktop\RideShare\RideShare\App_Data\RideShare.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

While this works on my local machine, if I want to open it somewhere else, I have to change the path up until the \Rideshare folder. Is there a way to provide the string from say

```
\App_Data\RideShare.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

?
When linking to different pages you can do something like ~/page.aspx, is it possible to do it with the connectionstring?

Comment: You want to use a relative path... take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833640/connection-string-with-relative-path-to-the-database-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently working on something similar. The way I achieve this is by setting a relative path like this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RideShare.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```